# Finding opposite side in triangle using sine returning wrong value

Tags: c#

I have no Idea what is wrong. I have converted my sin answer to degrees but It will not give me the correct answer but instead gave me a 4.18......
The correct output should have been around 2.8.

Input 1 = 4.9 and Input 2 = 35
On my calculator Sin(35) * 4.9 = 2.8....

```
output = Convert.ToDouble(Input1.Text) 
            * Math.Sin(Convert.ToDouble(Input2.Text)*180/Math.PI);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Math.Sin()` takes the angle in radians.

What you do are doing here

```
Math.Sin(Convert.ToDouble(Input2.Text)*180/Math.PI)
```

is converting input2 to degrees.

You need to multiply by `Math.PI/180` to convert degrees to radians.

**Edit:**
So you should use

```
Math.Sin(Convert.ToDouble(Input2.Text)*Math.PI/180)
```

Comment: I pointed out where the error was. Check the edit for the corrected expression.

Answer (score 0):

As has been stated in other answers, your operator precedence is backwards, you need to divide Math.PI by 180 rather than dividing 180 by Math.PI.  So, your function should be:

```
output = Convert.ToDouble(Input1.Text) * Math.Sin(
                                         Convert.ToDouble(Input2.Text)*(Math.PI/180));
```